# RVM Install Ruby without a network connection

Tags: ruby, rvm

I want install a Ruby version trough RVM without hitting the network.

All necessary files are on the machine.

RVM is installed in the `$HOME` directory of the user.

I have all necessary deb packages are installed.

The Ruby sources are in `$HOME/.rvm/archive` :

```
appsse@sandbox-dev:~$ tree -L 1 .rvm/archives/

.rvm/archives/
├── ruby-1.9.3-p374.tar.bz2
├── rubygems-2.2.2.tgz
└── rvm-stable.tgz
```

My environment variables:

```
appsse@sandbox-dev:~$ env| grep rvm|sort

OLDPWD=/daten/appsse/.rvm
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/daten/appsse//.rvm/bin
rvm_bin_path=/daten/appsse//.rvm/bin
rvm_path=/daten/appsse//.rvm
rvm_prefix=/daten/appsse
rvm_version=1.25.24 (manual)
```

**How I can install ruby without hitting the network ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [rvm documentation](https://github.com/rvm/rvm-site/blob/master/content/rvm/offline.md)

In order to do it offline you should:

1. Clean default gems: `echo "" > ~/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems`
2. Clean global gems: `echo "" > ~/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems`
3. Disable automatic dependencies ("requirements") fetching: `rvm autolibs read-fail`
4. Install Ruby: `rvm install 1.9.3-p374 --rubygems 2.2.2` (this may require sudo password for autolibs)

Comment: rvm install 1.9.3-p374 --rubygems 2.2.2 --disable-binary worked like a charm. thx